# Get name of current table being scanned over using MultiTableInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When using the new new `MultiTableInputFormat` class is it possible to obtain the name of the table that is currently giving you the key and values?

I tried searching for a special attribute in the context & configuration but came up unlucky.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer to this issue.  I dug around in the source for the various classes and found that internally they do something similar to this to get the table name.

`String tableName = Bytes.toString(((TableSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getTableName());`